# Como puedo implementar de forma recursiva la siguiente función ? (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

```
divisores:: Int -> [Int]
divisores 0 = []
divisores n = [m | m <- [1..n], mod n m == 0]
```

*Adjunto la redacción del problema en cuestión:
Implementar una función en Haskell que reciba un número entero n. La función deberá
generar una lista con todos los números enteros mediante los cuales el número n sea divisible,
incluyendo al 1 y al propio número n entre tales factores. Realizar las validaciones que necesarias.
Utilizar recursividad.*

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

En haskell hay varios *patrones* para procesar recursivamente una lista. El que te hace falta es el de *filtrado*, `filter` (Muchos de estos patrones están ya disponibles como funciones en el módulo [`Data.List`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-List.html)).

Para una lista de enteros, podríamos definir `filter` así:

```hs
filter :: (Int -> Bool) -> [Int] -> [Int]
filter _ [] = []
filter p (x:xs) | p x = x : filter p xs
                | otherwise = filter p xs
```

La función `filter` recibe una función de filtro, `pred`, y una lista, `xs`, y devuelve una lista con los elementos de `xs` que haya pasado el filtro.

Aplicándolo a tu caso:

```hs
divisores:: Int -> [Int]
divisores n = filter f [1..n]
  where
    f m = mod n m == 0
```

Aunque es más sencillo definir `filter` como *compresión de listas*, tal como enunciabas en la pregunta:

```hs
filter :: (Int -> Bool) -> [Int] -> [Int]
filter p xs = [x | x <- xs, p x]
```

Es una forma de ver la equivalencia entre las dos definiciones.